# Get Rails ActiveRecord tests to run for MySQL -- username in test/config.yml is ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activerecord

I've monkey patched ActiveRecord in a Rails app that I work on, and I'm trying to prepare to contribute a pull request. I'm currently getting stuck, trying to get the MySql tests run.

I'm using the provided test/config.yml file and have created a 'rails' user with no password. When I then try to run `rake mysql:build_databases`, I get...

```
ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'activerecord_unittest'
ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'activerecord_unittest2'
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

== EDIT

I added a `puts` to the `Rakefile` to see what it was trying to execute, and got...

```
mysql --user=rails -e "create DATABASE activerecord_unittest DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci "
```

... which looks fine. Executing that manually, I get the same error. Apparently, the --user option is being ignored. I ran `mysql --help`, and it looks like `--user` is the correct option to be passing.

Comment: those erros says you are trying to connect with user '', such thing dosen't exist

Comment: I know. What I don't know is why it thinks I'm trying to connect as that user when the config file specifies `username: rails`

Comment: upvoted your question to see if someone else comes by in rescue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get it working now.

The error message is very misleading. Actually, the correct username was being sent, but the user did not exist because I did not create it properly, resulting in the error.

Specifying a username of 'rails' results in a connection as `'rails'@'localhost'`, so the username that must be created is `'rails'@'localhost'`, not `'rails'`. I think I knew this a long time ago, but now I've been working with PostgreSQL for a long time, so had forgotten.